# How to calculate covariance using apply function in R?

Tags: r, apply, simulation

I'm trying to simulate two distributions and compare their covariance using two functions. But when defining my covariance functions, I run into an arrow:

`Error in apply(c(X, Y), 1, cov) : dim(X) must have a positive length`

This is my code so far:

```
X <- matrix(rnorm(30,0,2))
Y <- matrix(rnorm(30,2,3))

S2 <- apply(c(X,Y), 1, cov)
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I am not really sure, what your final goal really is giving X and Y.

But maybe `cov(cbind(X,Y))` is doing what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

We need `mapply()` here.

```
mapply(cov, list(X, Y))
```

Comment: Can’t be sure, but I don’t think this is what OP intended, especially since using `mapply` like this shouldn’t do anything different to `lapply` with the order of the arguments swapped.

Answer (score 0):

Try `sapply(list(X, Y), cov)`, `sapply()` takes a list, vector as input and the output is a `vector`.